# How to do reduce with index in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

My current solution is to run `with_index` and then `reduce` on the array.

```elixir
5..10 
|> Stream.with_index 
|> Enum.reduce(0, fn(num_idx, acc) ->
  {num, idx} = num_idx
  acc + num * idx
end)
```

Is there a method that attaches an element's index to the element and then run reduce on the array?

Comment: What you tried is perfectly fine, what more are you looking for?

Comment: @coderVishal yes I suppose it's already as simple as it can get.

Comment: Sound like you want some thing the same as Enumerable.each_with_index in Ruby

Comment: @cuonglm yes, but then I realized even in Ruby you still can't do something like reduce_with_index

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to remember that the `Enum.reduce` function must have two arguments. So you need to make changes accordingly.

What you did was perfectly fine. According to your specification you can also use `Enum.with_index`

Alternatively you can use an accumulator as a tuple, with one element representing an index and other the result.

```elixir
5..10 #Directly pattern match in argument list 
|> Enum.reduce({0,0}, fn(num,{index,current_result}) ->   
  {index+1,current_result + num * index}
end)
```

Answer (score 22):

Why not use `Enum.with_index`?

```elixir
5..10
|> Enum.with_index
|> Enum.reduce(0, fn({number, index}, acc) ->
  acc + number * index
end)
```

`.with_index` takes an enumerable and returns a keyword list with each element of the enumerable mapped to its index. So `Enum.with_index([:hi, :hello, :greetings])` would return `[hi: 0, hello: 1, greetings: 2]`. We can utilize the fact that Elixir keyword lists are lists of tuple pairs to pattern match in `.reduce`.

Answer (score 9):

You could do the pattern match directly inside the argument list:

```
5..10 
|> Stream.with_index 
|> Enum.reduce(0, fn({num, idx}, acc) ->
     acc + num * idx
   end)
```

Another option would be to first get the products via `Stream.map` and then use `Enum.sum` at the end:

```
5..10 
|> Stream.with_index 
|> Stream.map(fn {num, idx} -> num * idx end)
|> Enum.sum
```

Comment: ah that's right, I forgot about pattern matching inside the argument list, thank you!